# how to store a reference to just inserted div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, reference

I am doing this, but I end up with a reference to the wrong object, obviously.
How can I store a reference to the actual inserted DIV from the first statement below?

```
    //add the slide to module
    var slideWrapperRef = $('div#'+moduleId).append( "<div id='"+slideId+"' class='slide'></div>" )

    //add the contents of the slide to its wrapper div
    $(slideWrapperRef).append( html )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/):

```
var slideWrapperRef = $("<div id='"+slideId+"' class='slide'></div>").appendTo( $('div#'+moduleId) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the div in advance, storing the reference, then append it. What your code is doing is creating the div on the fly.

```
var $div = $("<div id='"+slideId+"' class='slide'></div>");
$('div#'+moduleId).append($div);
```

While you could reverse the order using `appendTo` like this:

```
$div = $("<div id='"+slideId+"' class='slide'></div>").appendTo($('div#'+moduleId));
```

I recommend the first approach as it is a little easier to read and debug. jQuery chains can get messy quick.

The main thing to note about this issue is that the first item of the chain is the reference that will be saved when setting a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
var newDIV = $("<div id='"+slideId+"' class='slide'></div>").appendTo$('div#'+moduleId)
```

Comment: It won't let me edit because it's too small, but you have a typo at the `appendTo$(`.